# Page number in top-right corner 15 mm from top

Tags: header-footer, geometry

I am using next snippet to set page number in top-right corner. It works fine for me, except I want to place page number exactly 15mm from top edge. Is it possible? Thanks.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} \chead{} \rhead{\normalsize\thepage}
\lfoot{} \cfoot{} \rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\normalsize \thepage} % Even page, Odd page; Right, Left, Center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Comment: You can set the correct lengths with `geometry`. Or use the package `atbegshi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage[tmargin=15mm]{geometry}
```

to have your type area start `15mm` from the page boundary. For other [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings, see the [`geometry` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).